# Force HTTPS in Neo4j configuration

Tags: rest, neo4j, haproxy

Is is possible force HTTPS URLs even when the `X-Forwarded-Host` header is not present?

**Update:**

We are using HAProxy in front of the Neo4j server. The configuration is

```
frontend proxy-ssl
  bind 0.0.0.0:1591 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/server.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend neo-1
```

This works well when every connection contains only one request. However, for Neo4j drivers which uses keep-alive (like Py2neo), the header is added only to the first request.

Without the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, the generated URLs are `http://host:1591`, instead of `https://host:1591`.

According to the [HAProxy documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#6), this is the normal behavior:

> since HAProxy's HTTP engine does not support keep-alive, only headers
>   passed during the first request of a TCP session will be seen. All subsequent
>   headers will be considered data only and not analyzed. Furthermore, HAProxy
>   never touches data contents, it stops analysis at the end of headers.

The workaround is to add `option http-server-close` in the *frontend*, so it will force that every request is in its own connection, but it will be nicer if we can support keep-alive.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like Apache or Nginx in front of your Neo4j server to perform that task.

Comment: We currently have an HAProxy, but it only adds the header `X-Forwarded-Host` to first request.

Comment: What's exactly the use case? You want to force SSL for connections from HAproxy to Neo4j server?

Comment: My initial question was too vague. I'm sorry. I have improved it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of py2neo, I can add some functionality to cater for this situation quite easily. What if I were to include `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` for all https connections? Would that cause a problem in cases where a proxy isn't used?

Comment: Hi Nigel. Thanks for the workaround, but it will be a pain to patch every Neo4j driver which is using HTTPS. With the `option http-server-close` in HAProxy it is working, though there is no keep-alive between Neo4j and the HAProxy. We hope to find a solution soon.